# This project was created in an older product version and cannot be directly migrated in the current version

Tags: migration, ibm-rad

I have a **RAD 8.5.1** installed in my system and I have imported an application which was designed using **RAD 7**. So when I import this app, I see the following errors. Looking to overcome these errors. Thanks

> This project was created in an older product version and cannot be
>   directly migrated in the current version.
>         To ensure a smooth migration please follow the two step migration process specified in the online documentation.
>           * The project nature: org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature is missing.
>           * The project file: .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component is missing.
>           * The project nature: org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature is missing.
>           * The project file: .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml is missing.

Answer (score 1):

RAD can only migrate projects from up to two major releases. Out there there are RAD 7.0, 7.5, 8.0 and 8.5. According to your scenario, you want to migrate from three release before 8.5.

Here the documentation that says this

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_8.5.1/com.ibm.etools.rad.migration.doc/topics/c_migrate_unsupported.html?lang=en

The easiest way to achieve this is, if you still have RAD 7.0 installed, exporting your projects with sources to archives (EAR or whatever you have) from RAD 7.0 and then importing them into 8.5 using its respective import wizard (Import EAR in this scenario).

Another approach is if you have a RAD 7.5/8.0 then you can migrate the projects from 7.0 to 7.5/8.0, and afterwards from 7.5/8.0 to 8.5 (7.5/8.0 means one or the other).

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_8.5.1/com.ibm.etools.rad.migration.doc/topics/t_migratefrom70.html?lang=en

Hope this helps